# Is there a way to specify duration of short-term project/freelance/contract/gigs offers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

StackOverflow (and perhaps other SE sites) have a "Jobs" section.

Is there a place/filter that would allow to specify a duration of the job/project?

E.g. 1-6 months projects/freelance/contract/gigs might be interesting to someone (like me).

---

Google/SO searches did not reveal relevant results to answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

There is a job type filter that allows you to filter by permanent or contract jobs.

[image]

Heres the url: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&type=contract

We don't collect duration information at this time so no filter is currently available for that.